# Xamarin iOS Fails Calling DataServiceQuery

Tags: xcode, xamarin

Just coming back to testing the iOS cross platform project of my solution today, I am receiving the error message "An error occured on client IDB4110776 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.11.0.776/stop-app" when trying to iterate the results of a DataServiceQuery, i.e.

```
foreach (IdentityEntitiesModel.Device device in response.EndExecute(result))
```

In general, looking at the response received, it looks basically ok, having the query path. It was working two months ago.

I am using Xcode 10.1 beta 2 (10O35n) against a iPhone with iOS 12.0 (16A366) from VS2017 15.8.5. Another developer just encountered the same error using Xcode 10 and IOS 10.14.1.

Where might I find details as to the "xvs/idb/4.11.0.776/stop-app" function?

Comment: Can you post a demo or code to help us reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using Facebook Auth.    2018-10-09 14:18:38.604 com.example.acc[531:158957] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2018-10-09 14:18:38.689 com.accomplish.dev.acc[531:158957] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB4110776 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.11.0.776/stop-app

Comment: Igor, Did you happen to update to Xcode 10.1 beta 2 or the OS on the device?

Comment: I regressed to Xcode 10.0 but error persists. It appears from the output that the error is related to iOS libraries:

Comment: 2018-10-09 12:27:47.107 xSentry.iOS[2274:1102461] critical:  0   xSentry.iOS                         0x00000001040d59c8 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 57413176
2018-10-09 12:27:47.108 xSentry.iOS[2274:1102461] critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001b50c6a20 <redacted> + 56

>>>>>>

 xSentry.iOS                         0x00000001041a4e2c mono_pmip + 809172
2018-10-09 12:27:47.113 xSentry.iOS[2274:1102461] critical:  11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b50d52fc <redacted> + 128

Comment: I have filed a support ticket with the Xamarin team.

Comment: Code Example: [link](http://public.thoughts.net/Examples/CodeExample.txt)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that iOS requires the call be marshalled to the main thread, i.e.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (IdentityEntitiesModel.Device device in response.EndExecute(result))
        {
            if (device.MAC == DeviceID)
        {
            activeDevice = device;
            activeICID = device.ICID;
            // Remark to debug new device
            DeviceFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message.ToString() + cr;
    }
});
```

The solution should work across platforms.